# How do I bypass the arguments in a method for testing in rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

How do I use an allow to receive to bypass the arguments in the method for testing?

I have two hashes in my spec which I want to use for `keys_1` and `keys_2` but I need to bypass `yaml_1` and `yaml_2` because I don't currently have any files to read from. How would I do this?

#### compare_code_spec.rb

```
let(:main_hash) {
  { navigation:
   { about: 'About',
     blog: 'Blog',
     contributors: 'Contributors',
     partners: 'Partners',
     privacy: 'Privacy Policy'}
   }
}

let(:second_hash) {
  { navigation:
   { about: 'About',
     blog: 'Blog',
     partners: 'Partners'} 
  }
}

describe '.compare' do
   subject(:subject) { described_class.compare(locale_1, locale_2) }

   it 'compares locales' do
      expect(subject).to eq(result)
   end
end
```

#### compare_code.rb

```
def compare(locale_1, locale_2)
  yaml_1 = YAML.load(File.open(File.expand_path(locale_1)))
  yaml_2 = YAML.load(File.open(File.expand_path(locale_2)))

  keys_1 = flatten_keys(yaml_1[yaml_1.keys.first])
  keys_2 = flatten_keys(yaml_2[yaml_2.keys.first])
end
```

Comment: The fact that you are going to bypass local variables inside your methods for tests typically arises from bad OO design. You can define another method `def config(locale)` that returns yaml file and stub it with your arguments.

Comment: allow(YAML).to receive(:load).and_return({test: 12345})